# How to hide video source for inspect element

Tags: php, wordpress

How to hide video source for inpect element becuase pf protection issue.i do not want give access to anyone save my videos.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way of hiding the URL, one thing you could do is create a PHP file that streams the video. But even then, anyone with Wireshark would know the actual origin location of the file.

I would take a look at this here: https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293

Basically what it does is it finds the origin file and streams it. So you could have a path such as

`http://example.com/video.php?v=myvideo.mp4`

And then in the VideoStream class you would define the origin location

```
$videostream = new VideoStream('path/to/file.mp4');
$videostream->start();
```

The nice thing about this as well is that it only streams the video in chunks instead of loading the whole file (imagine reading 2GB of Video in one go).

Comment: doesn't work the concept of obfucasting in HTML?